# Help me to fix my tramp (ssh/scp) workflow

Tags: tramp, ssh

I'm relatively new to tramp and despite being certain that it offers an elegant solution to my needs, I wasn't able to find one thus far. Let me briefly describe my workflow:

I connect to a server via tramp via ssh:user@host:path/ and there I usually edit a given text file. Commonly I have to upload a new document to the same file from my local machine. To achieve this, I (and this is the part I want to fix) open a separate eshell buffer in emacs and copy the file via scp to user@host:path/ . I then (which - again - is very undesirable) use this eshell buffer to connect (via ssh) a third time to the server to change the permissions of this newly uploaded file.

Clearly, this workflow is ridiculously inefficient and in desperate need of improvement. Can someone help?

---

I'd also like to disclaim that I searched for relevant questions on this side and found

- [Tramp/Dired transfers files inline over ssh instead of using scp externaly](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13797/tramp-dired-transfers-files-inline-over-ssh-instead-of-using-scp-externaly),
- [Executing remote commands with TRAMP with a single SSH connection](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24287/executing-remote-commands-with-tramp-with-a-single-ssh-connection) and
- [remote tramp eshell session changes to localhost](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22026/remote-tramp-eshell-session-changes-to-localhost).

However, I wasn't able to derive an answer of my question from them - probably due to the lacking knowledge on my part.

Comment: Could you clarify your specific question?  It's very open-ended right now.

Comment: @Dan I'm not sure how to narrow it, because I don't know exactly which solution I'm looking for. I'd like to find an efficient way to both edit text files on a given server and copy files from my local machine to it in emacs - preferably using tramp.

Answer (score 2):

For copying files from the local to the remote machine or vice-versa, I connect to the remote machine with tramp: 
<kbd>C-x d</kbd> `/ssh:user@host:/path/of/remote/dir`
I have the window split in two, on one side the local `dired` buffer and on the other side the remote one. So, I use `dired-do-copy` from `dired-aux` package.

**Edit:** forgot to add as [phils](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/454/phils) suggested, you havet to set `dired-dwin-target`:

```
(setq dired-dwim-target t)
```

Comment: How do I open dired in an ssh session?

Comment: Stefan: Exactly the same way as you open dired for *any* directory. Just use the tramp path. (Or use `C-x d` from your remote file buffer.)

Comment: I recommend setting `(setq dired-dwim-target t)`, which makes copying files between dired buffers easier, as the suggested default target directory will automatically be that of the other dired buffer.

Comment: @phils Thanks, I forgot about that. I have updated my answer.